# Deploy to stopped Ec2 instances or automatically when they are restarted

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, deployment, devops, aws-code-deploy

Currently we have some servers on AWS that are scheduled to come down and up. These are done through some python scripts.

I am looking for a way to deploy code onto these servers in a way that even if some are stopped, they can be "auto-deployed"/"updated" when they come back up. At the moment we have to run some scripts to bring those stopped servers up and then deploy but this can get tiring and hoping to improve on it.

We use Jenkins for our deploy pipeline and I was experimenting around with codeDeploy to see if that is possible but no luck so far.

We don't want to go with auto-scaling group for the time being and also are trying to move away from scheduling some scripts on each of those stopped servers that can update the code.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Just a query here, in order to deploy into any server, it has to be online. When we stop it, we will not be able to any type of connection till it comes online from other third party tools like jenkins , ansible etc. What is specific requirement to deploy to server which is in off mode? Can't we just make online, deploy and if not in use, just shut down it?

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. Its more so how we can make it so when the servers do come online eventually they can be auto-updated with the latest code without us having to re-run the deploy pipeline.